# AngularJS Function not getting called in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, quickblox

I am using quickblox with angularjs for xmpp chats. However, one of the functions inside my controller isn't getting called. Please let me know why:

```
function connectChat() {
        chatService = new QBChat({
            onConnectFailed: onConnectFailed,
            onConnectSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
            onConnectClosed: onConnectClosed,
            onChatMessage: function (senderID, message) {
                console.log('message received');
                /*
                 * senderID - QB user ID
                 * message.type - type of retrieved message
                 * message.time - time when message was created (using ISO standard)
                 * message.body - body of user message
                 */
                var entry = {
                    message: message,
                    style: 'opponent',
                    timestamp: Date.now()
                };
                $scope.data.push(entry);
                console.log($scope.data);
            }
        });
```

It works on the browser, but this is inside a phonegap/cordova app running on iOS and Android.

Other functions work but `onChatMessage` doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: why is this title *angular function not called* when it's a completely different library issue?

Comment: It's inside an angularjs controller... It works outside of it.

Comment: since callback is outside of angular have you tried using `$apply()`?

Comment: No i haven't tried it. Where should I use $apply();

Comment: anywhere in an angular app that scope is changed by external third party code

Comment: can you please provide an example on how to add this in this controller? As I don't want to edit the Quickblox js file.

Comment: `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.data.push(entry); })`

Comment: What goes into (entry) ? I'm sorry i'm not familiar with this? Do I need to edit the external .js file? or this goes into the current code i pasted in my question

Comment: code in question ... replace the `push` part with my update

Comment: instead of `Date.now()` try `var d = new Date(); timestamp = d.getTime();`

Comment: Huh? I think your comment is supposed to be somewhere else...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't offer much help with the Angular issue as I'm not so experienced with it. However please use the latest version of the SDK, it has an updated API: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk - and check the sample here for the new code: http://quickblox.com/alex/websdk/chat.html - let me know how it goes!

Comment: First @charlietfl is exactly right that digest cycle will not be triggered here. So you definitely want to trigger it manually with `scope.$apply` or `scope.$evalAsync` (scope could evaluate possibly even in the current DC). Not sure what your scenario exactly is, but if you're depending on this data to be loaded in specific time, you may consider trying out `$timeout` with small delay, this would also trigger the digest cycle.

Comment: How and where to you invoke `connectChat()` ?

Comment: `Other functions work but onChatMessage doesn't.`, can you see any `console.log` output from `onChatMessage` or nothing?